# Not able to access my web application outside the server (apache)

Tags: apache, windows-server-2012

I have setup a mapping application on a Windows 2012 server, with apache web server. The application is accessible using this [URL](http://198.38.92.247/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?mode=browse&template=openlayers&layers=all&map=D:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps/osm-google.map) within that server. But not able access outside the server.

I have given the IP in apache .conf file for the "listen" parameter. Hope that is fine.
The IP is pinging is pinging from the local machine.
The hosting support confirmed there is no firewall blocking the access.

What else should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The IP address, is it static?, and are your cgi settings configured properly and the permissions on your directories within the website?

Are you receiving any forbidden access or other related errors?

Your Apache httpd.conf, your php.ini, and your user.conf files should all be checked along with configuring the correct permissions on files and directories.

*Note: Edit config files with sudo, restart apache after making changes.

Comment: It is not static. I tried another url from same IP and that is accessible.

Comment: To access it outside of your network you will need a static IP.

Comment: Yes, I have one too. And I can access other sites/pages from that also.